# Why do the number of copy constructor invocations vary for these objects I am using for a vector?

Tags: c++

I don't get why a copy constructor is called 3 times for 1 object, 2 times for the other and once for the last one. Same thing with the destructors.

I know a copy constructor is called when using values and not a reference being passed. I just don't understand how the number of calls to it is determined after compilation

```
 Student::Student(string s1, string s2, string s3, float g)

 : number(s1), name(s2), majorPgm(s3), gpa(g)

 { 

   cout<<"-- Student ctor "<<name<<endl;

 }

 Student::Student(const Student& stu)
 { 
  cout<<"-- Student copy ctor "<<stu.name<<endl;
  name     = stu.name;
  number   = stu.number;
  majorPgm = stu.majorPgm;
  gpa      = stu.gpa;
}

Student::~Student()
{ 
  cout<<"-- Student dtor "<<name<<endl;
}
```

MAIN METHOD:

```
Student matilda("100567899", "Matilda", "CS", 9.0f);

Student joe("100234555", "Joe", "Physics", 8.3f);

Student timmy("100234888", "Timmy", "CS", 11.5f);

vector<Student*> comp2404;
 comp2404.push_back(&matilda);
comp2404.push_back(&joe);
 comp2404.push_back(&timmy);


vector<Student> vect2;
vect2.push_back(matilda); //3 cpy, 3 dtr
vect2.push_back(joe);     // 2 cpy, 2 dtr
vect2.push_back(timmy);   // 1 cpy, 1 dtr
```

output:

--Student copy ctor Matilda

-- Student copy ctor Joe

-- Student copy ctor Matilda

-- Student dtor Matilda

-- Student copy ctor Timmy

-- Student copy ctor Matilda

-- Student copy ctor Joe

-- Student dtor Matilda

-- Student dtor Joe

-- Student dtor Matilda

-- Student dtor Joe

-- Student dtor Timmy

-- Student dtor Timmy

-- Student dtor Joe

-- Student dtor Matilda

I know for the first vector, I am passing references, so the only constructor gets called not the copy. For the 2nd vector, I am passing non-reference objects but I don't understand the sequence of invoking the copy constructors and destructors

Comment: With C++ try and pass in things as constant references and include the `std::` prefix to be clear what you're dealing with, that is `const std::string& x` in preference to `string x`. The references avoid making needless copies. The `const` part helps with compiler optimizations and prevents accidental mutations.

Comment: vector does move/copy when reallocate.

Comment: You should know how `std::vector` grows first.

Comment: Also, logging in `Student& Student::operator=(const Student& stu)` might highlight some parts too.

Comment: Why not use GDB, set a breakpoint and look at the call stack? It will give you the full context, including line numbers.